# Custom visualization in Power BI

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

How do I create custom maps like below for Power BI?

[image: Custom map]

I just like this map and have been trying to explore, but how do I create such a visualisation?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own visuals can be done, but it would be rather complex given the example you've shown. It requires extensive knowledge of JavaScript and other languages and also a Power BI Pro license. Try this for a starting point to find out more: *[Tutorial: Developing a Power BI visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial)*

An alternative would be to implement Python or R visuals. Both feature a diverse set of visualization packages that could help with such an advanced visual. I remember geoplotlib as a package that does a quite similar visualization.

The easiest alternative is to find custom visuals developed by others at https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals